# How to close console when my tkinter GUI is running after converting it in exe format

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, console

I have created a GUI using tkinter in python 3.2, and I have converted it into exe format using pyinstaller. And when I run it there is console running with it, if I close the console the GUI also terminates, I don't want to show the console with it.

[image: Behind the image of gui and then the console:/]

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you're using Python 3.2?

Comment: @abarnert yes Actually I have to run it on rasberry py thats why I am using python, the version can be changed but I have to create it on python

Comment: @abarnert The link you have provided does not suggest any suitable answer for my question, so its not duplicate